# Medieval word for "boss"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am searching for a fitting word for a story I am writing. The setting is fictional medieval (so not fully historical correct), and there is a group of bandits who have a leader.

I am wondering, how the bandit members would call their leader. Sir? Boss? Or is there a better word?

- In my opinion, "sir" sounds too honorable for a bandit, doesn't it?
- And "boss" sounds like a modern word to me and reminds me of modern gangsters.

As stated in the `single-word-requests` tag rule, here an example sentence:

> "We’re ready, **sir**. Do you want the black horse?"

Comment: In the Oxford English Dictionary, the first citation for boss, meaning the person in charge is 1635: "1635   J. Winthrop Hist. New Eng. (1825) (modernized text) I. 174   Here arrived a small Norsey bark..with one Gardiner, an expert engineer or work base [= Du. werk-baas], and provisions", so you are right, boss is too modern. (The second use is 1653: "1653   F. Newman et al. Let. May in E. Hazard Hist. Collections (1794) II. 236   From our Place of Residence at the Basses house in the Monhatoes.]"  And the first with the spelling "boss" is from 1806.

Comment: Are you looking for a word that would have actually been used when your story takes place or a word that *sounds* like it would have been used? (If it's the former, a more precise date would be helpful, as the Middle Ages spans 1000 years.)

Comment: @Laurel It is OK that the word sounds like it has been used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***chief*** dates from medieval times.  The [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/31580#eid9473489) has several definitions for chief, but the one applicable to your case is:

> a. The head of a body of men, of an organization, state, town, party,
>   office, etc.; foremost authority, leader, ruler

and the OED has a citation from 1297:

> 1297   R. Gloucester's Chron. (1724) 212   Þo þe Romeyns were wyþ out
>   chef, dyscomfortd hii were

And the next two citations, of which the second is actually intelligible:

> 1475  (▸?c1400)    Apol. Lollard Doctr. (1842) 57   Wan any auerous or
>   couetous is canonizid..or maad cheef.
>
> 1483   Caxton in tr. J. de Voragine Golden Legende 399   She was made
>   abbesse and chyef of al the monasterye

From reading the entire entry for chief, one sees that chief was a word widely used in medieval times, in many ways.  For example:

> †8. The head town or city; the capital n.1 Obs.
>
> 1393   J. Gower Confessio Amantis III. 164   Whan Rome was the worldes
>   chefe

So I think the bandits could well call their chief, chief, and how they would have spelled it (chef, chefe, cheef, chief, chief) is irrelevant because they were probably illiterate.

Addendum: See also [Etymonline, chief](https://www.etymonline.com/word/chief)

Comment: The problem with these examples is that not one uses _chief_ as a noun of direct address.

Comment: @KarlG Scour medieval literature and find a term of direct address!  Maybe start with Beowulf?  Happy hunting.  Myself, I am sure the nuns addressed their abbess as chyef. :)

Comment: I myself would never have wanted to travel in the Middle Ages without  my personal chef and would be incessantly calling for him.

Answer (score 1):

I would try using the word **master** in this case. It doesn't sound too honorful, and doesn't sound modern. I got the idea from *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire,* when the evil Death Eaters talk to their leader, Voldemort.

Comment: What is *honorful* intended to mean? That’s not an English word.

Comment: @tchrist Google Translate translates it to German "ehrenvoll" which back-translates to honorably.

Comment: +1 for "master", but -1 for "honorful". What a dreadful word!

Answer (score 0):

"We’re ready, **Sire**. Do you want the black horse?"

[Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22we%20are%20ready%20sire%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8trvCndXbAhVGWX0KHWllCd8Q_AUIDygA&biw=1024&bih=646)

> For this we are ready, Sire, to employ our own lives, to the end that, rendering to you very humble service … ([Henry Martyn Baird, 1899](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=pjk9AQAAIAAJ))
>
> We are ready, Sire, to cooperate with you, by word and by deed* in the difficult but glorious path which you have chosen. ([1869](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ktkSAAAAYAAJ))